# Virtual Machine or a Cloud Server without IP Address?

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, cloud

Is it possible to create a virtual machine or a cloud server on a dedicated server without IP address, for example with a hostname, or something else?

The reason I'm asking this is because I want to create multiple virtual servers and connect them with SSH and install web servers on them, but I don't have available IP addresses.

Comment: Well there'll always be the localhost address. But in theory yes? But you you won't be able to network it to anything/ use the internet etc etc.

Comment: I've done it on my local network before, but this time I want to access the machines using the Internet.

Comment: Yes. Assign a private ip address for your VM's network interface (ex: 192.168.1.1) Then create a virtual interface on your host machine with a IP in same range (ex- 192.168.1.2).

   1. For SSH, you can first ssh host's public ip and then ssh to your VM via host's shell. (ssh root@192.168.1.1)
   2. To access VM web servers from internet (given that you have separate domain names for each VM), you can use apache mod_proxy on host machine to forward web requests to VMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

Long Answer:
What you are looking for are private addresses, due to this section of your question " connect them with SSH and install web servers on them, but I don't have available IP addresses"

http://whatismyipaddress.com/private-ip is a good explanation.

If you wish your machines to talk to each other they need to be on a network together.

What you may be referring to when you don't have IP addresses are globally reachable addresses used for public websites, etc.